# java - Cucumber on JUnit Test Failure Hook

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, junit, cucumber-jvm

We use Cucumber-JVM to script our acceptance tests and JUnit to execute them (via the JUnit Cucumber runner).  As these tests involve Selenium WebDriver, I want to be able to take a screenshot should my test fail (which I have the code for).

If I simply add a WebDriver onException hook, the screenshot won't be taken when an assertion fails.  I want to be able to add a JUnit execution listener to the Cucumber runner, but the API doesn't seem to support this (no addListener method on Cucumber.class).

Can anyone help?  Thanks team.

Comment: You also can checkout QMetry automation framework where you don't need to do all common stuff required for web/mobile automation. It is taken care by the framework it self https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/qaf-2.1.9/gherkin_client.html#benefits-of-using-qaf-gherkin-scenario-factory

Comment: yes [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf) has inbuilt feature for web and mobile automation needs. For example it has auto-capture screenshot feature for assertion/verification or test failure, which can be configured as per need using property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I generally take screenshots in the `@After` hook which gets called after every cucumber scenario. `@After` hook method takes a special `Scenario` object so that you can embed your screenshots in your reports. Here is an example on how to take screenshots in the event your scenario fails,

```
   @After
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
        try {
            if (scenario.isFailed()) {
                final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                        .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
            }
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that works wonderfully.  Is it possible to get the Scenario's title or steps in a Before/After method?  I'd like to have a readable title in my screenshot.

Comment: Not sure, why you want to do that. Cucumber html reports has title,tags, Gs,Ws,Ts and screenshot information. Scenario object cannot retrieve steps or titles. It has only information about tags ```scenario.getSourceTagNames()```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a total Cukes noob: I've since discovered how to embed data in a scenario report.  Thanks for all the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Geb in front of Selenium, I think you could just make use of geb.Browser.report() to take the screenshot.